# How do I attach my LVM RAID's to a new Ubuntu install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, software-raid

I have an Ubuntu 9 Desktop system that I mainly use as a media server. I have a 2TB RAID5 and a 500GB RAID1, both using LVM. The OS drive is a 4GB CompactFlash card which has finally run out of space. I want to put in a larger CF card and install the latest version of Ubuntu. What do I need to do in order to attach these RAIDs to the new install?

Comment: Since you're using Ubuntu for a server, I'd suggest you wait for the upcoming 12.04 LTS, which is now in beta1. There's no point in upgrading  now. Get a larger CF card, backup current OS and restore to new larger card. Upgrade next month when 12.04 is released.

Comment: Also, 4GB should be enough, maybe moving /home and/or /opt onto the RAID/LVM might free up some space.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have LVM volume groups configured on top of software RAID arrays?  Or are you describing something else?  Both the software RAID subsystem and LVM support auto-discovery and auto-assembly of devices; in most cases everything should Just Work.  Assuming that you don't accidentally overwrite your RAID elements as part of your install, everything should be discovered automatically.  You'll probably have to add entries to `/etc/fstab` by hand.

You can use the `mdadm` to assemble software raid devices.  [This document](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=408461), while a little dated, has some useful instructions.

You can use the `pvscan` to discover LVM physical volumes, and you can use the `vgscan` and `vgchange` commands to discover and activate volume groups.